# Trying to find an integral

Tags: calculus, integration, statistics

Having $X \sim C(0,1)$ and function $\psi_\phi(x) = \arctan(x - \phi)$ for an M-estimator $\phi^*$.

Trying to find an integral $(\mathbb{E}\psi_\phi(x))|_x^{'} = (\int_{-\infty}^\infty \arctan(x - \phi)\frac{1}{\pi(x^2+1)}dx)|_x^{'} = \arctan(x - \phi)\frac{1}{\pi(x^2+1)}|_{-\infty}^\infty$ for futher solving $\mathbb{E}(..) = 0$ equality.

Is this correct and derivative is equal to integrand in at the end of the segment?